# join doesnt work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got the following SQL and I am trying to convert it into active record query methods

I have the following tables

```
Customers (id, name)
CustomerPriceRelations (customer_id, sales_price_id) # jointable
SalesPrices (id, margin)
ProductSalesPrices (product_id, sales_price_id) # jointable
```

and I am trying to perform the following query

```
SELECT sp.id, sp.margin_percentage
                    FROM sales_prices sp
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN carrier_product_Sales_Prices ps
                        ON sp.id = ps.sales_price_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer_Price_Relations cr
                        ON ps.sales_price_id = cr.sales_price_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers c
                        ON cr.customer_id = c.id
                    WHERE c.id = 2 AND ps.carrier_product_id = 3
```

I've tried to use the joins method, but the result is never joined for some reason, any help?

```
SalesPrice.joins(:carrier_products, :customers).where(customer_id: 2, carrier_product_id: 3)
```

Comment: "the result is never joined" what result? You need to be much more specific on what is and isn't working.

Comment: When i join the tables on the SalesPrice table, no new fields are added to the result

Answer (score 0):

Rails standard behavior for joins() is INNER JOIN and not LEFT OUTER JOIN. INNER JOIN means that, unless there is a match, nothing will come up on both sides of the join. If you want to use LEFT OUTER JOIN you need to explicitly define it:

```
SalesPrice.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN carrier_product_Sales_Prices ps ON sales_prices.id = ps.sales_price_id").
           joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer_Price_Relations cr ON ps.sales_price_id = cr.sales_price_id").
           joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers c ON cr.customer_id = c.id").
           where("cr.customer_id = ? and carrier_product_id = ?", 2, 3)
```

Comment: just as my own query does, this returns a 'PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column sales_prices.customer_id does not exist'. Apparently it looks for the customer_id column on the SalesPrice instead of the jointable, how do i fix this?

Comment: sweet, that works, but can you explain why this works and not the other one? much appreciated

Comment: when you do a where(customer_id: 2, carrier_product_id: 3), it will try to find the fields in the sales_prices table, i.e. the database table your SalesPrice class is tied to. That's because the select is starting in SalesPrice.